# The difference between ~/ and ../

Tags: html, asp.net, url

I am wondering if someone can explain me, in details, the difference between this :

```
~/Images/delete.png
../Images/delete.png
```

What --**I think**-- I know (not sure at all) :

- ../ and ~/ is understand in the server side. (c#)
- ../ is understand in the client side but ~/ is not. (html and javascript)
- ../ and ~/ mean Parent directory
- When I use ~/ in the server side, it look like it is converted to ../ in the client side.

I tried to find a solution, but --**I think**-- google do not consider '~/' and '../' in the search bar.

PS : Someone  probably already asked this question. I did a lot of research but I did not find a clear answer. If you think someone did, please refer me to it.

Thank you.

**EDIT :**

Thank you for your answer.

So, the ~ is converted as the path to the root of the project.

Ex : localhost:8080/main/images/delete.png

```
~/images/delete.png ---- > ../main/images/delete.png ---- > localhost:8080/main/images/delete.png

../images/delete.png ---- > main/images/delete.png
```

So, the client code for the first url will be : **../main/images/delete.png**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In ASP.NET, `~` is the [project root operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116(v=vs.100).aspx) (**not** parent folder). ASP replaces it with the path to the root of the project.  It only works server-side because the `~` operator is special to ASP.NET, but not to a browser.

`../` means parent directory, and works anywhere.

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! This helped me to understand this concept ! :)

Answer (score 1):

`~/` is parsed on the server as the app root directory. It is a good way to refer to resources because the URLs will be correct wherever the app is installed. On the development server the root directory might be `http://localhost:8080/myproject/` and when deployed it might be `http://mydomain.com/`.

`../` is a relative URL, pointing to the parent of the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

`~` has no special meaning in URLs. It is just a character. It might have special meaning to something that interprets it on the server. e.g. ASP.NET maps it to the project root (when outputting pages, not when reading reading URLs from the server), and Apache is often configured to map `~foo` to `/home/foo/public_html/` on the file system.

`../` means "Go up one level of `/`s" and is resolved by the client.

Answer (score 0):

`'/folder'` = a site-root relative path

`'folder'` = relative path that is resolved against the current page path

```
'../folder/...'
```

= relative path that is resolved as a parent of the current page path

`'~'` is the asp.net specific root operator, which resolves to root of the current application.
You'll want to use this operator instead of '/' in asp.net server controls that reference resources. The ~ operator is recognized only for server controls and in server code. You cannot use the ~ operator for client elements.

To read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116%28v=vs.100%29.aspx